# What is the best way to access Google Calendar from ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api

I'm writing an app for a company that uses Google Calendar internally and would need to use events they already have in their calendar in the app. So I need to get read only access to their calendars from the app (namely I need the events title, start and end dates and attendee emails for all future events).

*What is the simplest way to do this in ruby* (I would need it to work relatively seamlessly on Heroku)?

I tried using the [GCal4Ruby gem](http://cookingandcoding.com/gcal4ruby/) which seemed the least outdated of the ones I found but I'm unable to even authenticate through the library (`HTTPRequestFailed` - `Captcha required error`) let alone get the info I need.

**Clarification:** What I'm talking about is the Google Apps version of the calendar, *not* the one at calendar.google.com.

Comment: Does the Google Apps version support private iCal addresses? If so, the ri_cal framework does a pretty good job at parsing .ics files.

Comment: Sadly private addresses don't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I got the api via GCal4Ruby working. I'm not exactly sure what went wrong the first time. Thanks to Mike and James for their suggestions. This is sample code I used for anyone interested:

```
require "rubygems"
require "gcal4ruby"

serv = GCal4Ruby::Service.new
serv.authenticate "username@example.com", "password"

events = GCal4Ruby::Event.find serv, {'start-min' => Time.now.utc.xmlschema, 
    :calendar => 'example-cal%40example.com'}

events.each do |event|
    puts event.title
    puts event.attendees.join ", "
    puts event.start_time
    puts event.end_time
    puts '-----------------------'
end
```

Comment: Thx for this sample i got it running 3 mins.

Comment: this looked to good to be true and indeed the direct login api stopped in 2012

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Google Calendar [private xml address](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37648) feature to pull out the needed data.

You could then parse it with hpricot or nokogiri to extract whatever fields you need.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to be supported in the Google Apps version. Though that would be ideal.

Comment: The domain admin for your Google Apps setup should be able to enable this -> [instructions](http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-howto/msg/bd4b7416102d5950)

Comment: Does that have other security implications?

Comment: Well, everything has security implications, so "yes". Without a doubt it is security through obscurity (don't share the URL); but it doesn't seem wildly irresponsible with the data either.

Comment: I'll try to get hold of the admin (though probably after the weekend) and update what can be done. Thanks for the help.